# Example with 〜だけでなくて、〜も patern that I don't understand

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm asking about a grammar patern found in Tobira, that is : 〜だけ{でなく(て)/じゃなく(て)}、〜も (not only 〜, but also 〜). In the grammar point, I can understand the given examples.

For more information, one can see this page that gives more details [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28678/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F-and-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6) about this patern.

I was talking about Netflix and Amazon Prime (two video on demande services), telling to my conversation partner that Netflix is already enough for me and I don't have more time to suscribe to Amazon Prime.
To give me an example using the patern mentioned above, she told me this :

**「Netflixだけじゃなくて、Amazonプライムも　というのは好きじゃありません。」**

But I don't understand this sentence, especialy with the patern 〜けど{でなく(て)/じゃなく(て)}、〜も, that cannot be translated here by "not only 〜, but also 〜".

The sentence give me more the impression to say "Not only I don't like Netflix, but I don't like Amazon neither.", while my conversation partner told me that she would say 「Nexflixだけでなく、Amazon Primもきらいです。」

Do you have any keys for me to understand the first bolded sentence she told me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't see けど in the sentence in bold.

Comment: Well sorry, I made a mistake in my first post using けど in the patern, but it's だけ in fact.